# What is the entropy variation when drying a wet surface with an absorbent cloth?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, surface-tension

A mass of water on a surface is considered as a hydrostatic thermodynamic system. It seems reasonable to assume that the internal energy of this system $U(S,V,A)$ depends on the entropy, the volume and the free area of the water (where a surface tension will exist), and that the [1-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form_(differential_geometry)) for internal energy can be written as:

$$\text{d}U = T\text{d}S - p\text{d}V - \gamma\text{d}A $$

here $T$ is the temperature, $S$ is the entropy, $p$ is the pressure, $V$ is the volume, $\gamma$ is the surface tension and $A$ is the free surface area of the water.

If we put the water in contact with an absorbent cloth, it will spontaneously pass into the cloth as the experience clearly shows. Therefore, it seems that we are dealing with an irreversible and spontaneous thermodynamic process, where the entropy should be increasing ($\Delta S > 0$). Assuming that the process is isothermal, we will have that the free water surface disappears, although the volume of water inside the absorbent cloth would remain unchanged.

**My questions are:**

1. How could we calculate the entropy increase in this process?
2. Which additional data do we need to know to quantify this increase?
3. Are the chemical potential of free water and the chemical potential of soaked water involved?

---

**My attempt:** Using the relation:

$$\frac{1}{T} = \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial U} \right)_{V,A}$$

It seems possible for an isothermal process:

$$\Delta S = \frac{\Delta U}{T} = \frac{U_f- U_0}{T}$$

I assume that the initial internal enegy is something like $U_0 = C_{V,A}T_0 - \gamma A + f(V_0)$ and the final internal energy is something like $U_f = C_{V,A}T_0 + 0 + f(V_0)$, so we have:

$$\Delta S = \frac{\gamma A}{T} > 0$$

I am not sure this is the right answer, since in principle creating a new surface requires energy (so maybe $U_f < U_0$) according to this reasoning. I suspect that the chemical potential of free water and soaked water (inside the cloth) are different and that this is what is implied by the water being absorbed, until the chemical potential in both media is equal.

Comment: what is $\gamma$?

Comment: @BobD surface tension!

Comment: It seems like you are viewing this system as a closed system whereas the potential for evaporation would make it an open system